# Layering a view on top another

Tags: views, theming, bootstrapping

I'm wondering is it possible to have a bootstrap views tab and within that tab content(images) with bootstrap views grid layout, therefore each tab would have images in grid layout.

Comment: It's hard to be sure what you're after exactly.  A Drupal view displaying images in a grid divided up into bootstrap tabs?  Should be possible if you theme the view output appropriately.  More detail?

Comment: Basically i'm looking to achieve a Drupal view displaying images in a grid,but this view is on bootstrap tabs.For instance I have a bootstrap tab view and in each tab has a view of images in a grid, tab 2 has another set of images in a grid and same for tab 3. hope this was clearer.

Comment: How would you split up the images into tabs?  Would it just be a number on each, like 8 on the first then the next 8 on the second?  Also would they all be displayed at once or would clicking on the tab re-load the page like a pager?